# How to render a Nuxt page as a response from an express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

My question is about how to trigger something like [res.render](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) with a nuxt page?

The project is utilising [nuxt-express](https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template) template - a combination of Nuxt & Expressjs.

I know that nuxt has: **[nuxt.render(req, res)](https://nuxtjs.org/api/nuxt-render/)** and **[nuxt.renderRoute](https://nuxtjs.org/api/nuxt-render-route)** but I can't seem to get it to work - or find any examples of it's use similar to the below code block where the render should occur after the promise has resolved.

I have previously handled this in other applications using res.render like so...

```
router.get('/', (req,res,next) => {
    dothePromise(req.query)
      .then(data => {
        res.render('pages/auth', {data:data})
      }
}
```

**Some further details that might be useful:**

The process is...

1) I enter a page on a third party system which makes a GET request to my express endpoint.

2) Once the promise is resolved in my application I need to return HTML content that is then populated in the third party system inside of an iframe.

*This is my first stackoverflow question - if I'm missing anything or should make adjustments to the question please let me know.*

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on Nuxt so I can't help you with certain details, but I can tell you that if you start off with a default `nuxt-express` project, you can edit `server/index.js` to include something like the following:

```
function doThePromise( query ) {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
                setTimeout( () => resolve( "hi" ), 500 );
        } );
};

app.get( '/foo', ( req, res, next ) => {
        doThePromise( req.query )
                .then( data => {
                        console.log( "rendering", res.renderRoute );
                        res.renderRoute( 'pages/foo', { data: data } );
                } );
} );
```

If you then create a vue document at `pages/foo.vue` and access `/foo` in your browser, the promise will resolve after 500ms and perform the callback which renders the route and displays the desired page.

This solution seems to work but does not address two things:

- The argument for `renderRoute` is actually supposed to be a context object containing `req` and `res` properties, according to [the documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/api/nuxt-render-route/). I don't know how you're actually supposed to forward data in the response, but this doesn't seem to be the appropriate way.
- I'm not even certain that `renderRoute` should be used in this way. In the documentation it's used within the resoultion of a Nuxt `Builder` object, which I suspect might be intended to be a one-time operation rather than something that you would call repeatedly each time a request is made. I'm not sure either way, but it would probably be best to check. It might pay to look over the `nuxt-express` page for some examples of how to render routes and pass data in the rendering process.

Good luck!

Comment: Tested this out today - couldn't get it to work when making a slight adjustment.

Nuxt by default has routes setup for all files in the /pages folder so in the example when the apt.get runs for /foo I think it's following the regular route.

Tried again but doesn't seem to work as expected:

`
app.get( '/foo', ( req, res, next ) => {
                doThePromise( req.query )
                .then( data => {
                        console.log( "rendering", res.renderRoute );
                        res.renderRoute( 'pages/testpage', { data: data } );
                } );
} );`